# Contacts folder replacing user profile

Tags: user-profiles

So I wanted to move some user folders that I don't use (favorites, contacts, links, ect..) into a dummy folder. Well, stupid me somehow made the contacts folder replace my user profile, so the location, instead of being C:\Users\User\Contacts, it's now C:\Users\User. Tried to restore default location, but it gave me invalid folder path, so I made another user folder with the same name as the account, gave me access denied. What my users folder looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume creating a new user profile and manually transferring the files to this new profile isn't an option?

Comment: Maybe i can try that.

Comment: Update your question when you do that.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize you needed a microsoft account to make another user account, I really would rather not do that. Because at the moment I don't need one with my current user account.

Comment: @Jeff- You absolutely DO NOT need a Microsoft Account to make another user account.

Comment: @Ramhound https://i.imgur.com/eKoBTzj.jpg

Comment: Ok, found out how to make another user account but I really don't want to do that, I already have all my settings perfectly on my current user account.

Comment: Why did you create a username with the same user, that creates all sorts of problems, and of course you can't access another user's profile directory without taking ownership of it.  You can easily transfer the settings there is enough a built-in tool to do so.

Answer (score 0):

(ITYM: "it's now C:\Users\Contacts")

But what does the Contacts folder contain?  Everything? (appdata, etc?)

I don't understand how this happened -- or, indeed, exactly what happened.  Is your username now "Contacts"?

I can't see this happening without a lot of things being broken.  I'd say your safest bet is to use System Restore to take it back to how it was, then try again.

Comment: Well, when you go into the contacts folder, all my user profile stuff is there, and the address bar says that it's c:/users/*user*. My username is still normal, it's just the folder that's been changed. Would a system restore work? I thought it was only for system files

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry if my question is pretty vague, here's some more screenshots to understand better. https://i.imgur.com/nV9BlRu.jpg, https://i.imgur.com/vDVl07w.jpg

Comment: @Jeff - Update your question.